# Printing out a string from a struct defined array

Tags: c, struct

When I run the code I only get "amsung" for the 2nd ID and a "" for the 4th, I tried putting some spaces into the string " . . . . Samsung" and it 'fixed it' so I'm thinking it's got something to do with how the struct array is defined or how the string is accessed. As I'm still new to structures and so I'm not too sure what's going on, any insights would be greatly appreciated.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

const char * getSize(bool size);
const char * getUHD(bool UHD);

typedef struct tvs {
    int id;
    bool size; //have 1-3 for small to large
    bool UHD; //0 or 1 is yes/no
    char brand[];
}  tv;


tv tvs[4] = {
    { .id=1, .size=false, .UHD=false, .brand="Phillips"},
    { .id=2, .size=true, .UHD=true, .brand="Samsung"},
    { .id=3, .size=false, .UHD=true, .brand="LG"},
    { .id=4, .size=false, .UHD=false, .brand="Panasonic"}
};

int main(){

    int answer;
    answer = -1;
    int scanf_result;

    while(answer != 0){
        printf("\nPlease choose a TV ID. [0 to terminate the program]\n");
        scanf_result=scanf("%d",&answer);

        if((scanf_result == 0)|(scanf_result == EOF)){
            printf("\n *** Please enter an integer. ***\n");
            answer = -1;
            }

        if(answer >= 1 && answer <= 4) {
            printf("Selected TV ID # %d: \nBrand: %s \nSize: %s \nUHD: %s", answer, tvs[answer].brand, getSize(tvs[answer].size),getUHD(tvs[answer].UHD));
        }
        else {
            printf("Please select a valid TV ID.\n");
        }
    }

    return 0;
}

const char * getSize(bool size) {
    return size == true ? "Large" : "Medium";
}

const char * getUHD(bool UHD) {
    return UHD == true ? "Yes" : "No";
}
```

Comment: You use of `answer` as index wrong. It should be `tvs[answer-1]...`. It may cause this, not sure.

Comment: Note that arrays in C use zero-based indexing.

Comment: The structure member `char brand[];` is a zero-sized array. Try putting a number inside the square brackets (big enough to hold all your brand strings).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see 3 problems i think

1. you need to give a size to your char brand[] or you need to malloc it.
2. in the main you use tvs[answer] but you need to use tvs[answer -1] to have the right one in the array (array start at 0)
3. in the main you else printf("please select a valid..."); will print it when you answer is 0.  but 0 is a valid one, it's for exit.

hope i helped you

Answer (score 0):

It did not compilied for me, only after changed `char brand[]` to `char* brand` or sufficiently large number into the brackets.

After that did not expereinced the issues you mentioned. Only the one that caused by `answer` used wrongly as index since indexing is start from 0 in C so it should be used as `answer - 1` in the `printf`.